# When I change the colour of the Image view in xcode it does not change on the storyboard, why is this?

Tags: ios, xcode, background, uiimageview

I keep trying to change the image view background color but it does not change on the story board, can anyone explain why this is happenning?

Comment: are you changing color in code side or in IB?

Comment: Paste some of your code here, that way people can have an idea of what is happening.

Comment: even if it doesnt reflect in storyboard. dont worry it will reflect while running

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why this question was down-voted. It's a legitimate issue and it's a storyboard problem, so no code is needed to reproduce it.

I don't know why UIImageView doesn't update the background color in the storyboard. Perhaps this is by design, but I don't see a reason for it. Perhaps it's an Xcode bug.

If you'd like your changes to show up in the storyboard, try subclassing UIImageView and making a new background color variable that's @IBInspectable as below. You can then set "refreshedBackgroundColor" in the storyboard and you will see your changes reflected.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class RefreshedImageView: UIImageView {

    @IBInspectable var refreshedBackgroundColor: UIColor = UIColor.clearColor() {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = refreshedBackgroundColor
        }
    }
}
```